# @afterThrowing advice vs try catch block

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am new to aspectj programming,and i just used @AfterThrowing advice to catch the exception thrown from any method. But i m bit confused. How is it different from try catch block. 
In which cases we should use this advice and in which cases we should avoid this advice?

Thanx in advance .

Comment: How to handle all the exception thrown by all the methods in a package? Will you add `try-catch` for all the methods?

Comment: but we handle exception for every method differently, as in we write different code in catch block for every method, then how does this advice help? we have to write advice for every method then how is it different from try catch block?

Comment: You can handle all the exception at one place in Advice and put your logic there based on exception type. If it's not generic then don't use Advice. What Advice does? It extracts the common parts of the application and moved in a separate file called Aspect and you can apply it declaratory. The classes should focus on business logic instead of exception handling that's not what they are made for. Does it make sense?

Comment: is it a good programming practise to use advice instead of try catch block?

Comment: If you are talking  about Exception Handling for whole application then you can use it, rest it depends on the application design. It's not always true to use Advice for try-catch block.

Comment: Ok.. thanx .. it cleared my doubts about advice to some extent.

Comment: Read more about Advice in Spring official documention or Spring in Action PDF.